# Failing to mount a disk that was working a day ago

Tags: filesystems, mount, hard-disk

I cannot boot into Linux properly. The linux only launch terminal. It is probably because it cannot mount /diskA_2TB. But I do not know what is the problem. Everything worked fine a day ago.
[image]
[image]

Is the disk somehow damaged? What could I do to fix that?

systemctl status

```
● systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-958a555d\x2d4941\x2d4b44\x2d9a04\x2d45c1e9050c1b.service - File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/958a555d-4941-4b44-9a04-45c1e9050c1b
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-fsck@.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-02-04 14:04:28 CET; 46min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-fsck@.service(8)
  Process: 498 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-fsck /dev/disk/by-uuid/958a555d-4941-4b44-9a04-45c1e9050c1b (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 498 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 04 14:04:17 desktopDebian93 systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/958a555d-4941-4b44-9a04-45c1e9050c1b...
Feb 04 14:04:28 desktopDebian93 systemd-fsck[498]: Error reading block 1290 (Input/output error).
Feb 04 14:04:28 desktopDebian93 systemd-fsck[498]: diskA_2TB: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
Feb 04 14:04:28 desktopDebian93 systemd-fsck[498]:         (i.e., without -a or -p options)
Feb 04 14:04:28 desktopDebian93 systemd-fsck[498]: fsck failed with exit status 4.
Feb 04 14:04:28 desktopDebian93 systemd-fsck[498]: Running request emergency.target/start/replace
Feb 04 14:04:28 desktopDebian93 systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-958a555d\x2d4941\x2d4b44\x2d9a04\x2d45c1e9050c1b.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 04 14:04:28 desktopDebian93 systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-958a555d\x2d4941\x2d4b44\x2d9a04\x2d45c1e9050c1b.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 04 14:04:28 desktopDebian93 systemd[1]: Failed to start File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/958a555d-4941-4b44-9a04-45c1e9050c1b.
```

fdiskl

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EZRZ-00Z
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A5905D62-CA9E-47D9-8955-13C823C0E295

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048 3907028991 3907026944  1.8T Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD10EZEX-08W
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 785FE55D-C760-4D56-9FC3-AC1EE9FDAD49

Device        Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1      2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2   1050624   59643903   58593280    28G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3  59643904   75782143   16138240   7.7G Linux swap
/dev/sdb4  75782144 1953523711 1877741568 895.4G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD5000AAKX-0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 58A872B6-675F-4ED1-BCBD-7DC525FD0293

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    616447    614400   300M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     616448    821247    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda3     821248   1083391    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    1083392  54331391  53248000  25.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5   54331392 126011391  71680000  34.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6  126011392 976773119 850761728 405.7G Microsoft basic data
```

**EDIT 1:**
After running `fsck /dev/sdc1` and reboot. The Linux was able to mount the partition and boot properly. I ran the `/usr/sbin/smartctl -a /dev/sdc` with following results:

```
smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [x86_64-linux-4.19.0-6-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-17, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Blue
Device Model:     WDC WD20EZRZ-00Z5HB0
Serial Number:    WD-WCC4M3KA1ZAD
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 2ba2941ab
Firmware Version: 80.00A80
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Feb  5 22:33:08 2020 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (26280) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 266) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x7035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       60
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   170   169   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       4458
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1425
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   091   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       6699
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1332
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       103
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   198   198   000    Old_age   Always       -       7610
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   120   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       27
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Aborted by host               80%        26         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%        25         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%        25         -
# 4  Conveyance offline  Completed without error       00%        25         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Is it OK?

Comment: Your 2TB WD Blue has uncorrectable errors, this looks like a failing drive. The automatic repair failed, you need to run `fsck /dev/sdc1` manually as the log suggests. While you're at it, post the output of `smartctl -a /dev/sdc`.
You can also check/replace the SATA cable when your computer is powered off, you never know...

Comment: Other sata cable did not make any difference. But `fsck` command helped and I could boot the system properly. Output from `smartctl -a` command is in the main question.

Comment: `Raw_Read_Error_Rate` non-zero is not good. How old is this disk? `Power_On_Hours` and `Load_Cycle_Count` seem very high. Maybe it's just dying.

Comment: The disk is not even 2 years old. It is still under warranty. But the warranty will expire soon. But I should make diagnostics by WD software if I want to return the disk and claim new disk or money back.

Comment: Warranty apparently ran out last week (27th January). If you've proof of purchase you might get that extended a few weeks.

Comment: I do not know about 27th January. I have a receipt with 7th February 2018 when I bought the disk.

Comment: @kocourOggy has the disk been on most of the last two years.  "Power_on_hours" is the best part of a year's continuous use.  That's 279 days in "two years".  If I'm honest, every disk I've had fail through wear and tear was a WD Blue.  That's anecdotal evidence of course, but I've begun to avoid them for anything that's going to be left on a lot.

Comment: I've had 4 different WD Blue disks so far. All of them were working fine. The oldest one is from 2014. The 2TB disk is the first one causing me any trouble. Paradoxically, the 2TB disk is the newest one. Thanks for the caution. I'll probably buy the WD Red edition next time.